# Can not reach docker container running in a swarm cluster

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

If that's interesting: OS: WIN10 (cygwin), code written in `Java`.

I followed [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/) example.

> I'd expect to reach the `service` in front of the `container`, which is running on port 80, using `myvm1IP:80` (browser ir curl). Somehow this does not work. Or am I missunderstoonding the port mapping of the service?
>
> ***:8080->80/tcp**

I got a running docker swarm cluster consisting of 2 nodes. 
**I am able to ping both of the running VMs**

I already downgraded the version as there were [issues with more recent version numbers](https://forums.docker.com/t/get-started-part-4-swarms-connection-refused/63317). Information about the engine using `docker inspect vmName`:

```
    "Engine": {
        "EngineVersion": "18.06.1-ce",
        "Labels": {
            "provider": "hyperv"
        },
```

I executed the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=192.168.178.82
      - MYSQL_DB=article
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=abcdefg
    networks:
      - webnet    

networks:
  webnet:
```

Both replicas started successfully and are able to connect to the local running database (assuming that, as I had a look at the logs and everything was looking fine). The container are up and running.

> **Output of docker ps -a**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
979ed7ea88b7        elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4   "java -jar articlese…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes               8080/tcp            getstartedlab_web.1.j1j41so8pz6atxqnq9fqqquk7
7684c3667025        elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4   "java -jar articlese…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes               8080/tcp            getstartedlab_web.2.r4kadvztiwgpckkuannnhcsea
```

> **Output of docker service ls**

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                         PORTS
gvyi9moxtpvq        getstartedlab_web   replicated          2/2                 elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4   *:8080->80/tcp
```

> **Output of docker-machine ls**

```
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
myvm1   *        hyperv   Running   tcp://192.168.178.88:2376           v18.06.1-ce
myvm2   -        hyperv   Running   tcp://192.168.178.89:2376           v18.06.1-ce
```

When I try to execute `curl myvmIP:80` I recieve

> Failed to connect to 192.168.178.88 port 80: Connection refused

as response. I'd expect recieving a `404` error code as there is no mapping for `/`. Am I wrong with this?

Comment: On the docker hub page (https://hub.docker.com/r/elps/articleservice), it says that you need to have multiple containers running

Comment: You seem to have the articleservice running, but not the other 3. I know nothing about what that image is trying to do. Are you sure that it should work without the other containers running?

Comment: To use all the endpoints you need all services running. But it is possible to view at least some of the content without the other services running. E.g. you need the articleservice and the catalogservice to add articles to the catalog.

Comment: How do you know that the http server is running in the docker container? I would expect the 404 if the server was running, but you had a bad request, like a bad password.

Comment: For instance, if I try to curl the same port on my own computer's IP address where I definitely don't have an http server running, then I get precisely the same error:

Comment: matt@mattpc:~$ curl 192.168.1.5:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.5 port 80: Connection refused

Comment: So in your case it seems that the error is simply because there is nothing running there. Either you didn't start the server correctly in your docker start command, or the port that the server is communicating on is wrong.

Comment: Of course there is nothing running on that port^^ To start the container I use `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose {name}`  (for docker-compose.yml see above). Thats exactly the question I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I simply tested switching all the ports I had, as I was kind of sure there was something wrong.

- The application itself and container was running on default port (8080)
- The server was redirecting incoming traffic on port 8080 to containers port 80 (where obviously is running nothing)

After switching the ports in service config (`docker-compose.yml`) it works fine.

So the working `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=192.168.178.82
      - MYSQL_DB=article
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=abcdefg
    networks:
      - webnet    

networks:
  webnet:
```

So incoming traffic gets redirected as follows:

> **Incoming traffic -> 80:`Service`->8080:`Container`**